# Fixing buildings that do not appear in 3D using Mapbox gl js?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, 3d, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to adopt this [Display buildings in 3D](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/) example, but I found out that in my city (Minsk, Belarus) some buildings look flat like this:

[image: flat building]

The coordinates of this particular building are 27.552516, 53.897726 (lon, lat).

I checked out the attributes os this building in OSM and didn't find any special:

[image: OSM attributes]

There is only a number of floors as data about height, but it's the same for the rest of buildings which appear volumetric.

I haven't changed the code yet so I don't leave it here because it's in the Mapbox example above. Could someone tell me how to fix that problem?

Comment: Solved, the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54213838/some-buildings-dont-appear-in-3d-using-mapbox-gl-js-how-to-fix-it)